# How to generate multiple controls from one control variable

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to create multiple controls(in this case a panel) from one control variable. What I mean by this is when I press a button 3 panels appear in different locations using one Panel variable. My current code looks like this

```
Panel panel = new Panel();
int panel_LOC = -60;
int i;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    i = i + 1;
    pane1_LOC = panel_LOC + 60;
    panel.Location = new Point(0, panel_LOC);
    panel.Name = "panelName_" + i.ToString();

    panel.Width = 1052;
    panel.Height = 50;
    panel.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(222, 222, 222);

    panelIWantToCreateTheControlsOn.Controls.Add(panel);
}
```

When I press the button it creates one panel with the desired properties at location 0,0. When I press the button for the 2nd time it creates a panel at location 0, 60 BUT it deletes the 1st panel. When I press the button the 3rd time it creates a panel at location 0, 120 and again it deletes panel 2.

This is not exactly what I want. I want panel 1 and panel 2 to stay and not get deleted. How do I create multiple controls from one variable that I can acces in every method and that doesn't delete the other controls on creation.

Comment: It doesn't delete the 1st panel, it just moves it to the new location. May I ask what it is you're trying to achieve? Why do you fell you have to use only one variable to hold reference to multiple Panel controls?

Comment: I'm making a to-do list app. You type in what you have to do and then it creates a panel with the typed in text inside of a label. I want to use one variable because all the panels are going to look the same, the labels are just going to have different text containing them. It saves data  and it prevents me from typing the same variable over and over again.

Comment: What I mean by my comment is that when I have code like: Panel panel1 = new Panel(); Panel panel2 = new Panel(); etc. It would be efficient since It'd require me to do that around the 50 times. I can't use a tab control or any other controls since they don't look as good as a plane panel. I should look into custom controls in the future I know

Comment: Create an instance of panel1 (with its controls, i.e. label, textboxes, ..) via the form designer(set its "Modifiers" property to internal and its "Visible" property to false). When you need a new instance of the panel, if it's the first one, do "panel1.Visible=true". otherwise use a new instance of the form to "move" its panel to current form: "Form1 tempfrm=new Form1() ;  tempfrm.panel1.Parent=panel1.Parent ; tempfrm.pane1.Location = ... ".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try instantiate the object inside the button click event. that way a new object is created each time you click the button

```
Panel panel = new Panel();                        //<<<<<<MOVE THIS LINE
int panel_LOC = -60;
int i;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    i = i + 1;
    Panel panel = new Panel();                    //<<<<<<TO HERE
    pane1_LOC = panel_LOC + 60;
    panel.Location = new Point(0, panel_LOC);
    panel.Name = "panelName_" + i.ToString();

panel.Width = 1052;
panel.Height = 50;
panel.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(222, 222, 222);

panelIWantToCreateTheControlsOn.Controls.Add(panel);
```

}

Comment: This means that I can't acces the panel variable outside the button1_Click method

Answer (score 0):

`panel` in your case reference always to the same instance, so instead of create new instance you just update properties of already existing one.

Because you already have all "hardcoded" values for panel - you need only create new instance of panel.

For accessing `Panel` variables outside you can create method for creating a panel

```
private Panel CreatePanel(string name, int locationY)
{
    var panel = new Panel();

    panel.Location = new Point(0, locationY);
    panel.Name = name;

    panel.Width = 1052;
    panel.Height = 50;
    panel.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(222, 222, 222);       

    return panel;
}
```

Then create panel in button click

```
int panel_LOC = -60;
int i;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    i = i + 1;
    var panelName = $"Panel {i}";
    panel_LOC += 60;

    var panel = CreatePanel(panelName, panel_LOC);
    panelIWantToCreateTheControlsOn.Controls.Add(panel);
}
```

Then you can access panel outside of button click

```
private Panel GetPanelByName(strinig panelName)
{
    return panelIWantToCreateTheControlsOn.Controls
                                          .OfType<Panel>()
                                          .FirstOrDefault(control => control.Name.Equals(panelName));
}

var panel2 = GetPanelByName("Panel 2");
// use panel
```

Or save all created panels to the `Dictionary<string, Panel>` and access them from there

Comment: This isn't going to work since I need to acces the panel variable outside of the button1_Click method. If I put the variable inside the button1_Click method I can't acces it in any other methods

Comment: @unknown then you could always make it a field of the class?

Comment: @Fabio Say I have the  first 2 methods you wrote and I have my own method called MyNewMethod. In the MyNewMethod I want to create an event when that triggers when I press on the panel. How do I do this using this code: this.panel.Click += New System.EventHandler(this.panel1_Click);

Comment: You can add it to the panel returned by method `GetPanelByName`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually create a new panel and use a list to keep track of them outside of your method.

```
List<Panel> MyPanels = new List<Panel>();
int panel_LOC = -60;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Panel panel = new Panel();
    MyPanels.Add(panel);
    panel_LOC = panel_LOC + 60;
    panel.Location = new Point(0, panel_LOC);
    ...
```

And you don't need to keep a variable i to count the panels, since a list will give you the count `MyPanels.Count`

Comment: So how do I acces the variables outside my method?

Comment: If it is other methods within that class, then MyPanels is a member of the class and its methods can refer to it.  If you are asking how to reference items in a list, you will want to learn how to use lists.  you can go here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Actually,@Fabio 's answer is better.  You already have a list of the panels in panelIWantToCreateTheControlsOn.Controls.  So you don't need to create your own list at all.  You just access them through that if you need to access them in other methods.  If you need your own handle to them, either a List or a dictionary (like Fabio suggests) will do the trick.